# Disappearing Columns (R)

Tags: r, function, scale, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language. I am trying to use the "scale" function on some data I created:

```
a =rnorm(100,10,10)
b = rnorm(100,10,5)
c <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 100 , replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.25, 0.22, 0.25, 0.25) )

d = data.frame(a,b,c)
d$c = as.factor(d$c)
```

I only want to use the "scale" function on the first two columns in this data set:

```
e = scale(d[,1:2])
```

However, this returns a data set with only two columns. I want to use the "scale" function on the first two columns, and keep the last column as is. That is, the final data set "e" should have 3 columns.

Is there a way to only apply the "scale" function on the first two columns?

Thanks

NOTE:

Of course, I could this manually:

```
d$a = scale(d$a)
d$b = scale(d$b)
```

But I am looking for a way to apply the "scale" function on multiple columns at the same time. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: `d[1:2] <- lapply(d[1:2], scale)`?

Comment: I will try this right now! If you have time, can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65757562/r-error-error-in-check-data-argument-should-be-numeric thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace the columns.

```
cols <- 1:2
d[cols] <- scale(d[cols])
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! If you have time, can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65757562/r-error-error-in-check-data-argument-should-be-numeric thank you!